# Double inequality containing the argument of a complex number and two angle values

Tags: complex-numbers

Thanks for taking your time to read this question.

I have come across an exercise which requires me to plot the area which satisfies these two conditions:

$$   |z|^2 -5|z| +6<0$$

$$ \frac{π}3≤arg(z)≤π$$

Now, I know how to solve the first one but the second one baffles my mind.

Correct me where I'm wrong:

$arg(z)$ is typically defined as $arctan \frac{y}x$

If I apply it to the double inequality above, I get $$ \frac{π}3≤arctan\frac{y}x≤π$$

Now, if we divide it into two inequalities and perform the *tangent* operation on both sides we get:

$$ \frac{y}x ≥ \sqrt{3}$$ and $$ \frac{y}x ≤ 0$$

Which of course has no solutions. However, looking at the inequality, I have a notion that (graphically) the solutions are all angles **between π and $\frac{π}3$, going clockwise**. However, I have no idea how to solve this. Can anyone help?

Note: I am making elementary errors and please be gentle as this is the first time I'm encountering these kinds of inequalities.

EDIT: As requested, providing the solution to the first equation:

Let $ |z| = t $

$ t^2 -5t +6 <0 $, therefore

$(t-3)(t-2)<0$

$ (t<3 \land t>2)  \lor (t>3 \land t<2)$

Substituting t and squaring we get:

1. $\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)} <3^2  \land \sqrt{(x^2+y^2)}>2^2$

Graphically this would represent the annulus represented by the two circles. The other set of equations has no solution.

Comment: Why would the be no solutions? The first inequality is equivalent to $y \ge \sqrt{3}x$ and the second to $y \le 0$ and $x\ne0$. This is fulfilled for example for $x = y= -1$ as $-1 \ge - \sqrt{3}$ is equivalent to $1\le \sqrt{3}$. Also, your graphic notion is correct, since the argument is precisely the angle a vector connecting the origin to the complex number makes with the real axis. Please show how you have solved the first one.

Comment: @ViktorGlombik I edited it.